# Using FFMPEG in a Visual Studio 2013 ultimate project, linking error LNK2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, ffmpeg, lnk2019

I'm trying to use FFmpeg library and TIFF lib in my project (I'm making a .dll and/or .exe also). I have searched through the answers provided in here and Google, and linked the /dev/include 64-bit (32-bit VS making 64-bit project) to Additional Include Directories and shared/bin (library files) 64-bit to linker->Additional Library Directories and did the Linker->Additional Depedencies->avformat.lib addition. I also copied the .dll files to my project folder, but I still keep getting the LNK2019. Here's how I use the libs and the output of the compiler:

```
extern "C" {

#ifndef inline
#define inline __inline
#endif
#ifndef UINT64_C
#define UINT64_C uint64_t
#define INT64_C int64_t
#endif

#include <libavcodec\avcodec.h>
#include <libavformat\avformat.h>
#include <libswscale\swscale.h>

}
#pragma comment(lib, "avformat.lib")

1>------ Build started: Project: GHSOM_V3, Configuration: FFmpeg x64 ------
1>  ffmpeg_io.cpp
1>ffmpeg_io.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol av_malloc referenced in function "struct AVFrame * __cdecl alloc_picture(enum AVPixelFormat,int,int)" (?alloc_picture@@YAPEAUAVFrame@@W4AVPixelFormat@@HH@Z)
1>ffmpeg_io.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol av_free referenced in function "struct AVFrame * __cdecl alloc_picture(enum AVPixelFormat,int,int)" (?alloc_picture@@YAPEAUAVFrame@@W4AVPixelFormat@@HH@Z)
1>ffmpeg_io.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol av_freep referenced in function "void __cdecl aviCloseWriter(struct tagAVIWriter *)" (?aviCloseWriter@@YAXPEAUtagAVIWriter@@@Z)
1>ffmpeg_io.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol av_rescale_q referenced in function "void __cdecl aviWriteFrame(struct tagAVIWriter *,unsigned char *)" (?aviWriteFrame@@YAXPEAUtagAVIWriter@@PEAE@Z)
1>ffmpeg_io.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol av_frame_alloc referenced in function "struct AVFrame * __cdecl alloc_picture(enum AVPixelFormat,int,int)" (?alloc_picture@@YAPEAUAVFrame@@W4AVPixelFormat@@HH@Z)
1>ffmpeg_io.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol avcodec_open2 referenced in function "void __cdecl initiate_avi_create(struct tagAVIWriter *,int,int)" (?initiate_avi_create@@YAXPEAUtagAVIWriter@@HH@Z)
1>ffmpeg_io.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol avcodec_close referenced in function "void __cdecl aviCloseReader(struct tagAVIReader *)" (?aviCloseReader@@YAXPEAUtagAVIReader@@@Z)
1>ffmpeg_io.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol av_init_packet referenced in function "void __cdecl aviWriteFrame(struct tagAVIWriter *,unsigned char *)" (?aviWriteFrame@@YAXPEAUtagAVIWriter@@PEAE@Z)
1>ffmpeg_io.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol av_free_packet referenced in function "void __cdecl aviReadFrame(struct tagAVIReader *,unsigned char *,int)" (?aviReadFrame@@YAXPEAUtagAVIReader@@PEAEH@Z)
1>ffmpeg_io.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol avcodec_find_decoder referenced in function "void __cdecl initiate_avi_open(struct tagAVIReader *)" (?initiate_avi_open@@YAXPEAUtagAVIReader@@@Z)
1>ffmpeg_io.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol avcodec_decode_video2 referenced in function "void __cdecl aviReadFrame(struct tagAVIReader *,unsigned char *,int)" (?aviReadFrame@@YAXPEAUtagAVIReader@@PEAEH@Z)
1>ffmpeg_io.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol avcodec_find_encoder referenced in function "void __cdecl initiate_avi_create(struct tagAVIWriter *,int,int)" (?initiate_avi_create@@YAXPEAUtagAVIWriter@@HH@Z)
1>ffmpeg_io.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol avcodec_find_encoder_by_name referenced in function "void __cdecl initiate_avi_create(struct tagAVIWriter *,int,int)" (?initiate_avi_create@@YAXPEAUtagAVIWriter@@HH@Z)
1>ffmpeg_io.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol avcodec_encode_video referenced in function "void __cdecl aviWriteFrame(struct tagAVIWriter *,unsigned char *)" (?aviWriteFrame@@YAXPEAUtagAVIWriter@@PEAE@Z)
1>ffmpeg_io.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol avpicture_fill referenced in function "struct AVFrame * __cdecl alloc_picture(enum AVPixelFormat,int,int)" (?alloc_picture@@YAPEAUAVFrame@@W4AVPixelFormat@@HH@Z)
1>ffmpeg_io.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol avpicture_get_size referenced in function "struct AVFrame * __cdecl alloc_picture(enum AVPixelFormat,int,int)" (?alloc_picture@@YAPEAUAVFrame@@W4AVPixelFormat@@HH@Z)
1>ffmpeg_io.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol sws_getContext referenced in function "void __cdecl initiate_avi_create(struct tagAVIWriter *,int,int)" (?initiate_avi_create@@YAXPEAUtagAVIWriter@@HH@Z)
1>ffmpeg_io.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol sws_scale referenced in function "void __cdecl aviReadFrame(struct tagAVIReader *,unsigned char *,int)" (?aviReadFrame@@YAXPEAUtagAVIReader@@PEAEH@Z)
1>tiff_io.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol TIFFClose referenced in function "void __cdecl tiffReadRGBA(char *,int *,int *,unsigned char *)" (?tiffReadRGBA@@YAXPEADPEAH1PEAE@Z)
1>tiff_io.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol TIFFGetField referenced in function "void __cdecl tiffReadRGBA(char *,int *,int *,unsigned char *)" (?tiffReadRGBA@@YAXPEADPEAH1PEAE@Z)
1>tiff_io.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol TIFFSetField referenced in function "void __cdecl tiffWriteRGBA(char *,int,int,unsigned char *)" (?tiffWriteRGBA@@YAXPEADHHPEAE@Z)
1>tiff_io.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol TIFFReadRGBAImage referenced in function "void __cdecl tiffReadRGBA(char *,int *,int *,unsigned char *)" (?tiffReadRGBA@@YAXPEADPEAH1PEAE@Z)
1>tiff_io.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol TIFFOpen referenced in function "void __cdecl tiffReadRGBA(char *,int *,int *,unsigned char *)" (?tiffReadRGBA@@YAXPEADPEAH1PEAE@Z)
1>tiff_io.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol TIFFWriteEncodedStrip referenced in function "void __cdecl tiffWriteRGBA(char *,int,int,unsigned char *)" (?tiffWriteRGBA@@YAXPEADHHPEAE@Z)
1>Video.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl DCT2d(double *,double *,long,long)" (?DCT2d@@YAXPEAN0JJ@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl ForwardDCT(class DataShuffle *,unsigned char *,char *,int,int,int,int,int,bool)" (?ForwardDCT@@YAXPEAVDataShuffle@@PEAEPEADHHHHH_N@Z)
1>Video.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl IDCT2d(double *,double *,long,long)" (?IDCT2d@@YAXPEAN0JJ@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl ExportVideoFromDCT(class DataShuffle *,char *,char *,int,int,int,int)" (?ExportVideoFromDCT@@YAXPEAVDataShuffle@@PEAD1HHHH@Z)
1>Video.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl CopyToZigZag(double *,double *,long,long,long)" (?CopyToZigZag@@YAXPEAN0JJJ@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl ForwardDCT(class DataShuffle *,unsigned char *,char *,int,int,int,int,int,bool)" (?ForwardDCT@@YAXPEAVDataShuffle@@PEAEPEADHHHHH_N@Z)
1>Video.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl CopyFromZigZag(double *,double *,long,long,long)" (?CopyFromZigZag@@YAXPEAN0JJJ@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl ExportVideoFromDCT(class DataShuffle *,char *,char *,int,int,int,int)" (?ExportVideoFromDCT@@YAXPEAVDataShuffle@@PEAD1HHHH@Z)
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to link other FFmpeg libraries as well (avcodec, avutil, etc). Same for libtiff.